# Return in .then(), when there are multiple .then()?

Tags: javascript, promise

Js is not my first language, by a long chalk. I code in 5 or 6 others, and am comfortable with callbacks, which means that I should be able to grok promises.

However, I inherited a node.js project with something like this (simplified), which makes me uncertain)

```
let promise = someFunction.then({return xxxx;});    

// lots of more code & promises

Promises.all().then(() => {return somethingElse});
```

I am comfortable with lots of promises and Promises.all() to wait for them all to resolve (although I am replacing all `.then` with `await` for cleaner code), ***BUT*** ...

that `return` inside a `.then`  disturbs me. If I understand correctly, `.then` just wraps an async callback - which could happen at any time, even before the rest of the code and that `Promises.all`, leaving some of the code unexecuted.

Am I correct to be concerned, or is there something that I am missing?

Tl;dr - is it ok to return inside a `.then`?

Comment: _"is it ok to return inside a .then?"_ - absolutely. Why does it disturb you? --- _"just wraps an async callback"_ - no, an async function returns a promise.

Comment: _"is it ok to return inside a .then?"_ - How else would you transfer something from the `.then()` callback to the next callback in the chain?

Comment: Returning a value from the `then` callback is [the core feature of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), so yes it's totally ok.

Comment: Could you share your actual code, please? The snippet you posted doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning inside `.then` is extremely common and fine to do. What it does is it produces a Promise that now resolves to the value returned (rather than to the value returned by the previous Promise). Example:

```js
// resolves to 1
const prom1 = Promise.resolve(1);

// chains off of prom1, resolves to 2
const prom2 = prom1.then(() => {
  return 2;
});

prom1.then(console.log);
setTimeout(() => {
  prom2.then(console.log);
});
```

This technique is very useful when you need to pass along a value from a prior `.then` to a subsequent `.then`.

```js
const makeApiCall = num => Promise.resolve(num + 3);

Promise.resolve(1)
  .then((result1) => {
    return makeApiCall(result1);
  })
  .then((result2) => {
    console.log(result2);
  });
```

What the return will do in your situation specifically:

```
let promise = someFunction.then({return xxxx;});    

// lots of more code & promises

Promises.all().then(() => {return somethingElse});
```

If `promise` is passed to the `Promise.all`, then its resolve value will be `xxxx`, rather than whatever `someFunction` resolves to. (If the `Promise.all`'s `.then` ignores its argument, then it does nothing except wait for the returned value to resolve, if it's a Promise.)

```js
const someFunction = () => Promise.resolve(1);
let promise = someFunction().then(() => {
  return 'xxxx';
});

Promise.all([promise]).then((allResults) => {
    console.log('allResults', allResults);
    return 'somethingElse';
  })
  .then((result2) => {
    console.log('Next `.then`', result2);
  });
```

Note that your current code has a number of syntax issues you need to correct.

Comment: Thank you ***very*** much for such a fast and detailed response. As I said, I find deeply nested `.then()` chains difficult to read and plane on replacing each with `await`. Presumably doing so to your answer would change nothing?

Comment: Sure, `await` is interchangeable with `.then`, and is more readable.